# Finding fastest path for robotic drive base

Tags: algorithm, physics, path-finding, robotics

I am trying to create an algorithm to find the fastest path a robot can take between 2 points in terms of time. The robot I would be using would be powered by a drive wheel on each side and have limited acceleration and velocity. I was also hoping to build in some obstacle avoidance so the robot is able to path around obstacles. I am familiar with pathfinding algorithms such as a* that find the fastest path in terms of distance between two points but this algorithm does not always find the fastest path for a robot with bounded acceleration and velocity.

I've been thinking about this for a couple days and honestly I'm not really sure where to start or where to find resources on the topic so any help is appreciated.

Example:

[image: img]

Lets say our robot is 10 units wide and each wheel has a maximum speed of 100 units/second and a maximum acceleration of 10 units/second/second.

At point A (x = 0, y = 0) the velocities of the robots wheels are 50 and 30 for the left and right wheels respectively and the robot is at a 30 degree angle relative to the x-axis. At point B (x = 1000, y = -600) we want the robot to be stationary and have a -75 degree angle relative to the x-axis

What is the most time efficient path for the robot to take from point A to point B given it's starting and ending velocities and headings while also avoiding the obstacles?

Comment: Can the robot spin in place (e.g. wheel speeds are -30 and +30)?

Comment: Yes, any speeds within the maximum velocity constraint are possible. In this example any speed between 100 units/second and -100 units/second are reachable.

Comment: The search terms `hybrid a*` and `hybrid a* stanford` get some interesting hits.

Comment: What are your results of 'thinking about this for a couple days'. Share your ideas / thoughts. I would start with a naive path (like driving on a manhatten-grid and using A*-Search for path-finding). Then I would try to improve this solution step by step.

Comment: @joeypow A* can handle speeds and accelerations you just need to change the cost to time instead of distance ... so you need to store in each maps cell the also speed vector so you can compute the time cos for neighbors ... there is a problem with obstacles as your robot must have enough space to stop so you need to have also map that shows min distance to nearest obstacle to limit speed ...